# How to optimize std::map insert() function?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dictionary, std

The best way to explain what I'm trying is accomplish is with this example (compiled with `Visual Studio 2008 SP1`):

```
struct ELEMENT1{
    //Its members

    ELEMENT1()
    {
        //Constructor code
    }
    ~ELEMENT1()
    {
        //Destructor code
    }
};


std::map<std::wstring, ELEMENT1> map;

std::pair<std::map<std::wstring, ELEMENT1>::iterator, bool> resIns;
ELEMENT1 element;
std::wstring strKey;

for(size_t i = 0; i < numberRepetitions; i++)
{
    //Do processing
    //...

    //set 'strKey'

    //Insert new element into the map first
    resIns = map.insert(std::pair<std::wstring, ELEMENT1>(strKey, element));    //This line calls ELEMENT1 constructor & destructor twice

    //Then fill out the data
    fill_in_data(resIns.first->second);
}


BOOL fill_in_data(ELEMENT1& outInfo)
{
    //Fill in 'outInfo' -- MUST be in its own function
    //...
}
```

My goal is to optimize this code, and thus I did the following:

- Moved `ELEMENT1 element` construction/destruction outside of the loop.
- I'm inserting the `element` into the `map` and then attempt to fill it out using the pointer to the inserted element instead of constructing new element, then filling it out, then copying it into the map, and then destroying it. (At least that was the plan.)

But when I compile this for a `Release` build and check the assembler code, I can see that the C++ line with `map.insert()` function calls `ELEMENT1` constructor twice! and then twice its destructor. So the following machine code is just for that `map.insert()` line:

[image]

So I'm obviously not seeing something here.

Can someone suggest what's going on in that compiled code & if it's possible to optimize it?

Comment: Can you upgrade compilers?  If you can then you can upgrade to C++11 and use `emplace` which was built to solve this problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, upgrading compiler is out of the question now. Maybe later.

Comment: Your std::pair type doesn't match map::value_type...

Comment: I'm the future could you post information like what you have in a screen cap as plain text or code-formatted text?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I tried. And it didn't look as nice as it does in that screenshot. SO formatting engine totally butchered it up.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have 2 constructor calls is because what you are passing to `insert` does not match what it need.  `std::map::insert` takes a `const value_type&` and `value_type` for a map is

```
std::pair<const key_type, element_type>
          ^^^^^ this is important
```

So, since they do not match you construct one element when you use

```
std::pair<std::wstring, ELEMENT1>(strKey, element)
```

and then the compiler calls the copy constructor to convert that into a

```
std::pair<const std::wstring, ELEMENT1>
```

A quick fix is to change the code to

```
std::pair<const std::wstring, ELEMENT1>(strKey, element)
```

Which leaves you with one temporary that is constructed and destructed.  You can also do as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660986/4342498) to avoid the creation of the temporary entirely.

Comment: Thanks, it did take care of one constructor. But there still another one remains, followed immediately by a destructor after `insert()` returns. Your code as well as doing `ELEMENT1& resIns = map[ strKey ];` both do this -- the latter one internally inside the template. Is there a way to just call an assignment operator instead?

Comment: @c00000fd You can't assign to an object until it is constructed meaning your going to have at least one constructor call.  With `ELEMENT1& resIns = map[ strKey ];` you should only have a single constructor call.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I get only one call with that and also with your method.

Comment: A quick follow-up. Is it something specific for `std::map` that constructor is called to add each element? Because `std::vector` doesn't have such requirement.

Comment: @c00000fd No, this is not unique,  Every element in the vector is also constructed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> resIns = map.insert(std::pair<std::wstring, ELEMENT1>(strKey, element));
> ```

You are constructing a temporary `std::pair` whose member `second` is a `ELEMENT1`. This causes the *copy constructor* of `ELEMENT1` to be called.

The 2nd call to the copy constructor of `ELEMENT1` is when `std::map::insert()` creates a new element in the map that will be initialized by the temporary `std::pair`.

You can avoid the duplicate constructor call caused by the temporary by using [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) instead:

```
ELEMENT1& resIns = map[ strKey ];

fill_in_data( resIns );
```

If `strKey` doesn't already exist in the map, an `ELEMENT1` will be default-constructed directly within the map and a reference to the new object will be returned. The constructor will be called exactly one time.

If `strKey` already exists in the map, a reference to the existing object will be returned.

Comment: It is indeed an elegant solution, and it got rid of one constructor... but there still one remains. Is there a way to make it use assignment operator instead?

Answer (score -1):

You should use emplace to avoid creation on temp objects:

```
resIns = map.emplace
(
    ::std::piecewise_construct
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple(strKey)
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple()
);
```

A good reason to switch to newer VS version.

Comment: VS2008 does not support C++11/`emaplce`

Comment: Not me, the OP.  I have a question to him asking if he can upgrade.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `piecewise_construct` here? Wouldn't `emplace(strKey, element)` suffice?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Without `piecewise_construct` we won't be able to emplace something like this `map.emplace(strKey);` invoking value default constructor.